# Error when installing p4python on osx-MountainLion

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, p4python

I have Python version:
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

downloaded p4python from http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis#p4python

```
tar -zxvf ./p4python.tgz
```

downloaded p4api from ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/bin.darwin90x86_64

```
tar -zxvf ./p4api.tgz
```

placed extracted files into p4python directory

Then I run:

```
sudo python ./setup.py build --apidir ./p4api
```

I get the following error:

```
API Release 2012.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 434, in <module>
    do_setup(p4_api_dir, ssl)
  File "./setup.py", line 349, in do_setup
    info = PlatformInfo(apiVersion, releaseVersion, ssl != None)
  File "./setup.py", line 279, in __init__
    self.ID_OS = self.inStr(unix + release + platform)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'release' referenced before assignment
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit setup.py, change below:

```
elif unameOut[2][0:2] in ("10", "11") :
```

to

```
elif unameOut[2][0:2] in ("10", "11", "12") :
```

cause `uname -a` we got 12.10 on mountain lion

```
Darwin csjteki-MacBook-Pro.local 12.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.1.0: Tue Aug 14 13:29:55 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.9.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```